# Why doesn't my paste special work properly?

Tags: excel, vba

When I run the code below, my range, Master, pastes twice, once with content, and once with empty cells.

```
Sub AddProj() 'Adds new template to Data Worksheet

    Sheet1.Range("Master").Copy
    Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlFormats
    FindProj

    End Sub
```

When my code is like below, it works properly but doesn't paste formatting:

```
Sub AddProj() 'Adds new template to Data Worksheet

Sheet1.Range("Master").Copy Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

FindProj

End Sub
```

FindProj is just some function to copy and paste a cell:

```
Sub FindProj() 'Finds project name in Historical Worksheet and pastes it in Data Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Newproj As Long
Dim Master As Range
Dim Masterrow As Long

Masterrow = Worksheets("Data").Range("Master").Rows.Count
Lastrow = Sheets("Historical").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Newproj = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Historical").Cells(Lastrow, "B").Copy Sheets("Data").Cells(Newproj - Masterrow + 1, "C")

End Sub
```

Also, the first code only works once and then never again.
Obviously the `PasteSpecial` is messing things up but I can't see why. Is there a way to incorporate `PasteSpecial` into the second code?

Comment: What does Findproj do. Can you add that code?

Comment: @Scott_Craner added the FindProj code.

Comment: Run your code without FindProj  and see if the error persists

Comment: The code doesn't run regardless.

Comment: @GMalc hard coding the range defeats the purpose of the code being the way it is. What I'm hearing is that I can't just add to my code PasteSpecial.xlFomats. Is there a way to incorporate PasteSpecial in the second version of the code? Because that code works, it would just be nice if it could keep formatting so I can color the first cell to make the data more legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this help?

```
Sheet1.Range("Master").Copy
With Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

Comment: It works with just one of them. If I use both PasteSpecial commands, it stops working.

Comment: Sorry, you have to do two separate paste specials without the With statement.
`Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`
`Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats`